# How does SOAP webservice supports ACID property

Tags: java, soap, soap-client, webservice-client

I read that SOAP web service when compared to REST supports ACID property.Could anyone explain this for me with an example?

Comment: We can not compare SOAP with REST, SOAP is a protocol while REST has different levels to achieve RESTfull web services.

Comment: ACID property is a part of database not of web services . you should take care of ACID only  when you try to communicate with db not at service where r u calling.

Answer (score 1):

Web Services Atomic Transaction (WS-AtomicTransaction) Version 1.2

Web Services Coordination (WS-Coordination) Version 1.2

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13734/transaction.htm#WSADV382

"This specification defines three specific agreement coordination protocols for the Atomic Transaction coordination type: completion, volatile two-phase commit, and durable two-phase commit. Developers can use any or all of these protocols when building applications that require consistent agreement on the outcome of short-lived distributed activities that have the all-or-nothing property."
http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-tx/wstx-wsat-1.2-spec-cs-01/wstx-wsat-1.2-spec-cs-01.html

"The framework enables existing transaction processing, workflow, and other systems for coordination to hide their proprietary protocols and to operate in a heterogeneous environment."
http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-tx/wstx-wscoor-1.2-spec-cs-01/wstx-wscoor-1.2-spec-cs-01.html

"Web services provide an automatic transaction mechanism. Any web method can automatically run within the scope of a transaction. All you need to do to take advantage of this capability is add a property to the WebMethod attribute—there's no extra code required. If an exception is thrown from within the web method and not caught, the transaction will be aborted automatically; if no exceptions are thrown, the transaction is committed. You can catch exceptions within the web method, but then you have to throw an exception—after you've performed any steps that you need to perform—in order to abort the transaction. This article shows you how to use automatic web service transactions effectively."
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30231&seqNum=2